`pipenv install` does not properly install mysqlclient while `pip install` does
brew install mysql-client
mkdir foo && cd foo
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib/pkgconfig"
pipenv install mysqlclient
pipenv run python -c 'import MySQLdb'

exits with an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/foo/.local/share/virtualenvs/foo-cSg51m4-/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/foo/.local/share/virtualenvs/foo-cSg51m4-/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-312-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.24.dylib
  Referenced from: <74CE3BA6-6CF0-3583-93EC-6F733D03E6C3> /Users/foo/.local/share/virtualenvs/foo-cSg51m4-/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-312-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/libmysqlclient.24.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/lib/libmysqlclient.24.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/lib/libmysqlclient.24.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/lib/libmysqlclient.24.dylib' (no such file)

and
brew install mysql-client
mkdir foo && cd foo
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib/pkgconfig"
pipenv run pip install mysqlclient
pipenv run python -c 'import MySQLdb'

exits with zero.
This is unintuitive. Why does pipenv work differently? Is it an intended behavior?
Environment: macOS 14.4 arm64 (M3) / Python 3.12 (Homebrew)
I have no idea where to start investigating. Python's dependency management is too complex to me.

have seen UV. python package management is a nightmare however,   UV has made it a lot easier. designed to be like rust package management but for python.  worth switching over in my opinion. https://github.com/astral-sh/uv

Thank you @MPathan for introducing a great project! Unfortunately, I don't have a choice to replace the package manager at my work :(

this thread by be useful  https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3873.

Solution:
pipenv install --extra-pip-args '--force-reinstall --no-cache-dir' mysqlclient

The root issue was that pipenv reuses the cached wheel, which had been incorrectly built.

Please do like this.
brew install mysql-client

Add the following to your shell configuration file (.zshrc, .bashrc, etc.):
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib/pkgconfig"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

(By including DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, we ensure that the dynamic linker can locate libmysqlclient.24.dylib during runtime. This should resolve the import error you are encountering.)
Then, source the file:
source ~/.zshrc  # or source ~/.bashrc

And then,
mkdir foo && cd foo
pipenv --python 3.12
pipenv install mysqlclient
pipenv run python -c 'import MySQLdb'


Sorry, It's not working for me. The same error message.
